# android - listview and Adapter does not show any item:(

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem in my Android application. I have a Custom ListView Adapter, but when I launch the application the list does not show any item!

My Code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AccountContents extends Activity {
    private ListView ls1;
    String username = fourshared.username;
    String password = fourshared.password;
    private AccountItem[] rootContents;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rootContents = fourshared.rootContents;
        CArrayAdapter adapter = new CArrayAdapter(AccountContents.this, rootContents);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ls1 = new ListView(AccountContents.this); 
        ls1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the list to your activity. To do this, add this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and remove: **setContentView(R.layout.main);**

This will add the list into view, but remove the existing views.

or you can define a list in your xml, and, as mentioned above, find it like this:

```
ls1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
```

and in xml:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/ls1" ......allOtherAtributesHere...... />
```

Comment: Thank You, it's Work.  i have define a list in layout.

Answer (score 2):

Does your layout contain a list view?  If so, you should look that up and set the adapter on that:

```
ls1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
```

Better still, make your activity a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and Android will do a lot of the work for you.

Comment: Adapter  not reloading for me